# How to simulation an Ajax call just like Postman does?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, postman

I have used Postman to get json data from an url. The result is good and I've got an array as json string. Below are the images I captured during using Postman to get the data:

[image: Header]

[image: Body]

I want to do this in Ajax call, but don't know how to implement that. This is an example that I have tried:

```
function getDeliveryStatusDetail(qrcode) {
var url = 'http://thecompany.com/DeliverStatusDetail/DeliverStatusDetail';
var data = JSON.stringify({ QRCode: qrcode });
$.ajax
  ({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      async: false,
      data: data,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'lgGbkiJ1n2RtjaXLHzvHs7yejzejt+0O4ELj7im8PzYGAOyTO');
      },
      success: function () {
          alert('Thanks for your comment!');
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
      });
}
```

A successful return json look like this:

```
    {
  "QRCode": "KLO00998",
  "ReceiverAddress": {
    "FullName": "Elizabeth Jerah"
  },
  "QRCodeDetail": [
    {
      "QRCode": "KLO00998",
      "Status": "A"
    },
    {
      "QRCode": "KLO00998",
      "Status": "T"
    },
    {
      "QRCode": "KLO00998",
      "Status": "B"
    },
    {
      "QRCode": "KLO00998",
      "Status": "C"
      "SignatureReturn": ""
    }
  ],
  "code": "100",
  "desc": "Success",
  "ErrorMessages": null,
  "ValidationMessages": null

    }
```

The code above could simulate the process of Postman, but unsuccessful. Could you help me to reformat the example code?

Comment: postman doesn't have to follow all the same-origin policies that ajax does.

Comment: I am not sure what's your question? are you asking how to make an ajax call ?

Comment: Let me add an example.

Comment: @Trind07 but... you used `jsonp`, that's not what you're doing in postman. jsonp is sent by appending a `<script>` tag to the html page, and as such there's no xhr to attach an authorization header to, and also can't be sent as a POST or be synchronous.

Comment: jsonp help to skip the error of cross-domain policy.

Comment: @Trind07 what's the response given after the request?

Comment: @Trind07 you can't just stick "jsonp" on any old request and expect it to fix CORS. well, you can, but you'd be wrong.

Comment: You can't fix a CORS problem with client-side code. the server has to be fixed to support CORS or an alternative to CORS such as JSONP.

Comment: Look like I have to do this from code behind using C#. I will come back later to give a new idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I have came out with a new solution in C#. Event my question is not relative to the C# but this is my only solution to solve this issue.

```
 var httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://mycompany.com/DeliverStatusDetail/DeliverStatusDetail");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Alpha lgGbkiJ1n2RtjaXLHzvHs7yejzejt+0O4";

            using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"QRCode\":\"HS2016000\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Label1.Text = result;
            }
```

I was plan to call ajax on client side, but got a stuck like what I've described in the question. Then I tried it on server side by establish a HttpWebRequest in C# and can get the result after running the code in ASPx page.

Comment: Found a working solution in python `import urllib
import urllib2
import base64

url = 'http://mycompany.com/DeliverStatusDetail/DeliverStatusDetail'

authKey = base64.b64encode("Alpha:lgGbkiJ1n2RtjaXLHzvHs7yejzejt+0O4")
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":"Basic " + authKey}
data = { "QRCode":"HS2016000"}

request = urllib2.Request(url)

request.add_data(urllib.urlencode(data))

for key,value in headers.items():
  request.add_header(key,value)

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

print response.info().headers
print response.read()`